# QUERY_STRING Rewrite order

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have the following rewrite rules which are rewriting to the same location:

## http://test.com/finance/payroll/forms/salary-payment-form.shtml?staff=test-edu-trust -> TO ->https://www.test.com/finance/BBBB.shtml?staff=test-edu-trust

```
RewriteRule %{QUERY_STRING} ^staff=test-edu-trust$
RewriteRule ^/finance/payroll/forms/salary-payment-form.shtml$ https://www.test.com/finance/BBBB.shtml?staff=test-edu-trust[R=301,L,NC]
```

## http://test.com/finance/payroll/forms/wages-payment-form.shtml?staff=test-comm-rac -> TO -> https://www.test.com/finance/BBBB.shtml?staff=test-comm-rac

```
RewriteRule %{QUERY_STRING} ^staff=test-comm-rac$
RewriteRule ^/finance/payroll/forms/salary-payment-form.shtml$ https://www.test.com/finance/BBBB.shtml?staff=test-comm-rac[R=301,L,NC]
```

The problem is both rewrite to the same location - https://www.test.com/finance/BBBB.shtml?staff=test-edu-trust

If I change the order of the rules to below then they end up rewriting to the first location in order: https://www.test.com/finance/BBBB.shtml?staff=test-comm-rac as per below:

```
RewriteRule %{QUERY_STRING} ^staff=test-comm-rac$
RewriteRule ^/finance/payroll/forms/salary-payment-form.shtml$ https://www.test.com/finance/BBBB.shtml?staff=test-comm-rac[R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule %{QUERY_STRING} ^staff=test-edu-trust$
RewriteRule ^/finance/payroll/forms/salary-payment-form.shtml$ https://www.test.com/finance/BBBB.shtml?staff=test-edu-trust[R=301,L,NC]
```

What is causing the order of the rules here just to rewrite to the first one defined as I thought the QUERY_STRING would have caught this and sorted which url to rewrite to ??

Comment: Just noticed i have RewriteRule and not RewriteCond in for the QUERY_STRING !! Doh !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed i have RewriteRule and not RewriteCond in for the QUERY_STRING !! Doh !!!